# How do I show that $-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - \bar{X})^{T} \sum^{-1}(X_i - \bar{X})=-\frac{n}{2}trace(\sum^{-1}S)$?

Tags: variance, multivariate-analysis

In multivariate statistics the variance $S=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - \bar{X})(X_i - \bar{X})^T.$

My lecturer showed me that $-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i - \bar{X})^{T} \Sigma^{-1}(X_i - \bar{X})$ is equal to $-\frac{n}{2}trace(\Sigma^{-1}S)$ through using S. However I do not understand how he got to this equation. Could someone illustrate the steps taken to get this equation please?

Comment: What dreadful notation with $\sum$ seeming to be almost the same as $\Sigma$. Be that as it may, are you _sure_ that your lecturer did not start from $\displaystyle(X-\bar{X})^T\Sigma^{-1}(X-\bar{X})$ instead of $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\bar{X})^T\Sigma^{-1}(X_i-\bar{X})$? The point is that $(X_i-\bar{X})$ is a _scalar_ or $1\times 1$ matrix and thus its multiplication by the $n\times n$ matrix $\Sigma^{-1}$ is either trivial or undefined

Answer (score 2):

You should be aware of the identity $\mbox{trace}(ABC)=\mbox{trace}(BCA)$.  This cyclic permutation identity makes it easy to derive many formulas that involve traces and products of the form $x^{T}Ax$ and $Axx^{T}$.  Note that the trace of a scalar is that scalar, so $x^{T}Ax=\mbox{trace}(Axx^{T})$.

Comment: Thanks. Also could you clarify whether the right hand side of my equation be equal to $-\frac{n}{2}trace(\Sigma^{-1}S)$ or $-\frac{1}{2}trace(\Sigma^{-1}S)$.

Comment: I believe that $-n/2$ is correct.  The $n$ factor cancels out with a $1/n$ in the definition of $S$.